# how to use moment js utc time to get a countries different timezone

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have the following populated list of timezones that a user can select
example

```
{name: '(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West', offset: '-12:00:00'}
{name: '(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11', offset: '-11:00:00'}
{name: '(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands', offset: '-10:00:00'}
{name: '(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey', offset: '-06:00:00'}
{name: '(UTC-06:00) Saskatchewan', offset: '-06:00:00'}
```

when the user selects a timezone how do i get the actual time and date of the zone they selected?

i can get the following local time as follows

```
var today = Moment();
        this.date = today.format("dddd,D MMM YYYY");
this.times = Moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
```

But im not sure how to get the timezones of the different locations. so for example if they selected
**(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West** how do i show the date and time of that location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Since your're using Moment.
- you can use **moment-timezone.js**
- Check docs here: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Example From Docs:

```js
let moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```